# How to execute OLEload script from cmd

Tags: teradata

I had builded .amj script from Teradata OLELoad GUI which connects to access and load data 
to Teradata ?

I was able to successfully run the script using OLELoad GUI Utility.

Is there a way to run .amj file from command prompt ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have access to any other Teradata utilities such as BTEQ or FastExport?

Comment: Yes I have access to Utilities . I am connecting to access through odbc and pull data to teradata in OLEDB GUI . But after examining the generated script it does not contain any ODBC Connection Details . It looks it only work with OLEDB GUI . Any Thoughts will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

When you launch the script with OLELoad you have to use a TTU as Fastload, Bteq or whatever. You can do the same from the command line. You just have to call the TTU you choose (for example Fastload) with your script in the parameter section.

Example:
Bteq.exe < Your_script.txt

You mention that you are using an amj file. That file must be referred into your script.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference the .AMJ file as part of an INMOD on some of the Teradata Utilities. Refer to the Teradata Tools and Utilities Manual for the Teradata OLE DB Access Module **[here](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/Interface_Tools/B035_2425_071A/2425ch02.11.18.html)** for examples.